# How to solve ImportError: dlopen(): Symbol not found:.... Expected in:

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
niko@xujiahuideMacBook-Pro tudui % tensorboard --logdir      
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/niko/anaconda3/envs/tudui/bin/tensorboard", line 6, in <module>
    from tensorboard.main import run_main
  File "/Users/niko/anaconda3/envs/tudui/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorboard/main.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorboard import default
  File "/Users/niko/anaconda3/envs/tudui/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorboard/default.py", line 33, in <module>
    from tensorboard.plugins.core import core_plugin
  File "/Users/niko/anaconda3/envs/tudui/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorboard/plugins/core/core_plugin.py", line 32, in <module>
    from tensorboard.util import grpc_util
  File "/Users/niko/anaconda3/envs/tudui/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorboard/util/grpc_util.py", line 24, in <module>
    import grpc
  File "/Users/niko/anaconda3/envs/tudui/lib/python3.9/site-packages/grpc/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from grpc import _compression
  File "/Users/niko/anaconda3/envs/tudui/lib/python3.9/site-packages/grpc/_compression.py", line 15, in <module>
    from grpc._cython import cygrpc
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/niko/anaconda3/envs/tudui/lib/python3.9/site-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): Symbol not found: __ZN4absl12lts_2023080219str_format_internal13FormatArgImpl8DispatchINSt3__117basic_string_viewIcNS4_11char_traitsIcEEEEEEbNS2_4DataENS1_24FormatConversionSpecImplEPv
  Referenced from: <FC38DEA6-6E9F-3D1D-8B1A-6C956FD6A13F> /Users/niko/anaconda3/envs/tudui/lib/libgpr.26.0.0.dylib
  Expected in:     <119804C8-C1A1-3372-B6AD-70B80BCDD732> /Users/niko/anaconda3/envs/tudui/lib/libabsl_str_format_internal.2308.0.0.dylib
```

I'm using a Macbook m3
python versions 3.9.18